If I am using Spring Security and Spring AI how do I make it so MessageChatMemoryAdvisor is per session?
I currently have a simple working prototype with Spring AI. Currently this is setup like
    @Bean
    public ChatClient buildClient(
            MessageChatMemoryAdvisor messageChatMemoryAdvisor
    ) {
        return openAiBuilder
                .defaultAdvisors(
                        messageChatMemoryAdvisor,
                        questionAnswerAdvisor
                )
                .defaultSystem(instructions)
                .defaultOptions(new OpenAiChatOptions())
                .build();
    }
    @Bean
    public MessageChatMemoryAdvisor messageChatMemoryAdvisor() {
        return new MessageChatMemoryAdvisor(new InMemoryChatMemory());
    }

the problem is this saves the messages for every request, not just the ones for that user. I have Spring Auth setup with a session getting created so it would make sense for the MessageChatMemoryAdvisor to use that but I am unsure how to do that.
What would be the best way to store the message history per session?
My Guess
I think I need to set a conv ID from the session ID like
@Slf4j
public class CustomMessageChatMemoryAdvisor extends MessageChatMemoryAdvisor {
    public CustomMessageChatMemoryAdvisor(InMemoryChatMemory chatMemory) {
        super(chatMemory);
    }

    private AdvisedRequest addSessionAsConversationId(AdvisedRequest advisedRequest) {
        String convId = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getSessionId();
        // Create map with session ID as conversation ID
        Map<String, Object> contextMap = new HashMap<>();
        contextMap.put(CHAT_MEMORY_CONVERSATION_ID_KEY, convId);
        return AdvisedRequest.from(advisedRequest)
                .withAdviseContext(contextMap)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public AdvisedResponse aroundCall(AdvisedRequest advisedRequest, CallAroundAdvisorChain chain) {
        return super.aroundCall(addSessionAsConversationId(advisedRequest), chain);
    }

    @Override
    public Flux<AdvisedResponse> aroundStream(AdvisedRequest advisedRequest, StreamAroundAdvisorChain chain) {
        return super.aroundStream(advisedRequest, chain);
    }

    public List<Message> getMessages(String conversationId, int chatMemoryRetrieveSize) {
        return this.getChatMemoryStore().get(conversationId, chatMemoryRetrieveSize);
    }
}

But I am not sure.

Basically instead of per conversation id I want it to be per user session id

Another approach would be to setup the conversation ID as the sessionId but not sure how that works either
